# How to restore component state from URL

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, state

Suppose the user requested the following page:

```
.../user/12/123
```

I have the following `Route`

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState(0);
const [data2, setData2] = useState(0);
...
<Route path="/user/:data1/:data2">
    <MyComponent data1={data1} data2={data2}/>
</Route>
```

How can I restore/update the state from the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to save the URL parameters in the state, just use [`useParams()`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook to access the params. `useParams()` returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters.

This is same as accessing the URL parameters in class-based component using `this.props.match.params`

```
const { data1, data2 } = useParams();

...
<Route path="/user/:data1/:data2">
    <MyComponent data1={data1} data2={data2}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work because `useParams` needs router context. So I need to use `useParams` inside `MyComponent` or create a wrapper.

Comment: If your route is `/user/12/123` and you want to access route parameters, i.e. 12 and 123 inside the `MyComponent`, using `useParams` inside `MyComponent` will give you access to route parameters. I am not sure what else you are trying to do.

Comment: I accept your answer because it moved in the proper direction. You can see that I mean below.

Answer (score 0):

I have a component which can be rendered as follows:

```
<MyComponent pn={..} parts={..} onPost={..} />
```

As now I need to use routing so I was forced to create a wrapper and put it into routes:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/user/:pn"><MyComponentWithRouter onPost={handlePost}/></Route>
    <Route path="/user"><MyComponent pn={initialPn} onPost={handlePost}/></Route>
</Switch>

function PppWithRouter(props)
{
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
    const pn = props.pn !== undefined ? props.pn : useParams().pn;
    const parts = searchParams.get("parts") || "";
    
    return <MyComponent pn={pn} parts={parts} onPost={props.onPost} />
}
```

What bothers me now is that if I choose to continue this way I need to write such a wrapper for most of my components.